# MS Access Database Check Box List Filters Missing On SQL Server back end

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

When I connect Access 2007 to SQL Server (whether by ADO recordset or by linked table) I no longer get check box lists (of available filter values) in the datasheet column filters.

Is this feature available only with MDB/ACCDB and/or DAO?

Comment: The only checkbox list in datasheet view that I know of is the multivalue field available in ACCDB format. It's not supported in SQL Server so far as I know, and shouldn't be used by anyone who doesn't need it for Sharepoint compatibility.

Comment: This has nothing to do with multi-valued fields.  It is the checkbox list you see showing all the available values in a column when you are FILTERING a datasheet.  In a datasheet view, next to each column header there is an arrow.  If you click it you get a choice of filters as well as all the availble values assuming there aren't too many different values (e.g., a location field but not a dollar amount field).  Very important and valuable feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the check box in datasheet view of native Access tables is governed by the "Display Control" property in the table design.  I don't recall what's available when the table is in SQL Server.  If you provide a form in "datasheet view", you should be able to bind a check box control to the SQL Server column.

**Edit**: I think I misunderstood your question yesterday.  If you click the Office Button, select Current Database, then put a check in the "ODBC fields" box under "Filter lookup options" ... does that do what you want?

Comment: You nailed it!  Thanks.  Nobody else knew the answer to this on other forums.

Comment: For Access 2010, go to the File tab > Options > Current Database then scroll down to "Filter lookup options..."

Comment: YES! I checked the ODBC Fields checkbox and I got this issue solved! MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I know we're breaking protocol by not opening a new question, but I'm going to answer this nevertheless so this thread will be complete.  This is a more complete answer than the previous ones.

I think I have this topic nailed down now.

The lookup filters won't work with a recordsource that is not an Access object, and they don't work in linked tables directly.

You have to create a query of the linked table, for example: Select * from tblOrders, and use that query as the recordsource in order to get the lookup filters.

HOWEVER, I found a more flexible approach as well.  I create passthrough queries to SQL/Server and use that as my recordsource.  Then, in code, I set the SQL of the passthrough queries like this:

```
Currentdb.QueryDefs("qpstOrders").SQL="Select * from Orders where OrderID =" & Me.OrderID
```

In the current event of my subform, I change the query on the fly to pass the appropriate record -- or it can just be a more generic query.  The lookup filters work fine this way and the interaction with SQL/Server is lightning fast.

Comment: Nobody will ever see this. It's great information, but since it was not posed as a real question, nobody will ever find it.

Answer (score -1):

Open the database that you want to optimize.

Click **File > Options** to open the **Access Options** dialog box.

In the left pane of the **Access Options** dialog box, click **Current Database**.

In the right pane, under **Filter lookup options**, mark **"ODBC Fields"** check box.

Comment: This was already answered by Hansup 11 years ago...  Your answer is a duplicate of his.