# Access VBA Columns quick fiter doesn't work when datasheet form is bound directly to MS SQLServer using DAO and ADO

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado, dao

Columns quick filter doesn't work when datasheet form is bound directly to MS SQLServer using either DAO or ADO.

Some error message appears but seems like not connected with the real problem...
i.e. :

- "operation is not supported for this type of object" (DAO connection)
- "cannot initiate data provider" (ADO connection)

Do you have the same problem when binding datasheet form directly to sql database using DAO or ADO?

I tried to check also:

File tab > Options > Current Database then scroll down to "Filter lookup options-> ODBC Field

but does not work

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: *Some error message* -- please post it, even if you think it's unrelated. Also, what exactly do you mean by *datasheet form is binded directly to MS SQL Server using DAO* ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access Database Check Box List Filters Missing On SQL Server back end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751849/ms-access-database-check-box-list-filters-missing-on-sql-server-back-end)

Comment: I tried to do what was written in possible duplicate topic but without positive result - the message which is shown is "operation is not supported for this type of object" It happens when I try to filter some column (I can do it at a first time but without any result and then I cannot do anything: clear previuos filtering, new sorting, any other new filtering)